# How do I subtract a shape in css

Tags: css, material-ui, clip-path

Im trying to create a frame that has `borderRadius: '150px 30px 30px 30px',` , however I want the top left radius to be flat [as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmCec.png).

I created a rotated rectangle in `::before` pseudo element which I thought I would subtract to get that flat look on the top left corner of the frame.

```jsx
<Box sx={{
  position: 'relative',
  width: '360px',
  height: '506px',
  border: `3px solid ${palette.black[900]}`,
  borderRadius: '150px 30px 30px 30px',
  boxShadow: `10px 10px 0px ${palette.black[900]}`,
  '&::before': {
    content: '""',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    top: '100px',
    left: '-100px',
    maxHeight: '100px',
    maxWidth: '300px',
    transform: 'rotate(-45deg)',
    transformOrigin: '0 0',
    background: '#D9D9D9',
    border: `3px solid ${palette.black[900]}`,
    zIndex: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
}}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using a pseudo element to create the border shape.

- Remove the `border` on the `Box` itself as we will add it to the pseudo element.
- Add non-`auto` `z-index` value to create a stacking context so that we can add the pseudo element behind any content but still make the pseudo element visible.
- Remove the top-left `border-radius` since we will be making our own chamfered edge

```
<Box sx={{
  position: 'relative',
  zIndex: 0,
  width: '360px',
  height: '506px',
  borderRadius: '0 30px 30px 30px',
  boxShadow: `10px 10px 0px ${palette.black[900]}`,
}} />
```

For the pseudo element:

- Fill the parent element by setting `position: absolute; inset: 0`.
- Have it be behind all content by setting a negative `z-index`.
- Transfer the `border` to it.
- `inherit` the parent's `border-radius`.

```
<Box sx={{
  …
  '&::before': {
    position: 'absolute',
    inset: 0,
    zIndex: -10,
    border: `3px solid ${palette.black[900]}`,
    borderRadius: 'inherit',
    content: '""',
  },
}} />
```

However, we still don't have our chamfered edge. First, let's add the `clip-path`:

```
<Box sx={{
  …
  '&::before': {
    …
    clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 150px, 150px 0)',
  },
}} />
```

You will find that the `border` does not follow the `clip-path` and instead gets clipped. To work around this, we can draw in our own border with a background `linear-gradient()`:

```
<Box sx={{
  …
  '&::before': {
    …
    background: 'linear-gradient(135deg, black 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat top left / 149px 149px',
  },
}} />
```

Full example:

```js
const { Box } = MaterialUI;

const palette = { black: { '900': '#000' } };

function App() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{
      position: 'relative',
      zIndex: 0,
      width: '360px',
      height: '506px',
      borderRadius: '0 30px 30px 30px',
      boxShadow: `10px 10px 0px ${palette.black[900]}`,
      '&::before': {
        position: 'absolute',
        inset: 0,
        zIndex: -10,
        border: `3px solid ${palette.black[900]}`,
        borderRadius: 'inherit',
        content: '""',
        clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 150px, 150px 0)',
        background: 'linear-gradient(135deg, black 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat top left / 149px 149px',
      },
    }} />
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@v5.14.1/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```